# Filter Array of Objects based on if the Parent is already inside the Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Lets say i have an Array of Objects that looks like this.

```
let example = [
      {
        data: { id: 1, group: 200, name: "Artist" },
        children: [{
          data: { id: 2, group: 201, name: "Album" },
          children:[{ 
            data: { id: 3, group: 202, name: "Song" },
            children: [],
            parentId: 2
          }],
          parentId: 1
        }],
        parentId: null
      },
      {
        data: { id: 2, group: 201, name: "Album" },
        children:[{ 
            data: { id: 3, group: 202, name: "Song" },
            children: [],
            parentId: 2
         }],
         parentId: 1
      },
      {
        data: { id: 3, group: 202, name: "Song" },
        children: [],
        parentId: 2
      }
    ];
```

Now i want to filter that Array, so it looks like this:

```
      [{
        data: { id: 1, group: 200, name: "Artist" },
        children: [{
          data: { id: 2, group: 201, name: "Album" },
          children:[{ 
            data: { id: 3, group: 202, name: "Song" },
            children: [],
            parentId: 2
          }],
          parentId: 1
        }],
        parentId: null
      }]
```

**EDIT:**

It should be filtered by whether or not the parent is already in the Array.
That includes that if Parent Object is inside the array as a child from another object.

Forexample: If the Parent of "Album" is in the Array remove "Album" from the Array etc.

Here is what i tried:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j17dqbor/)

I dont know how i would check if the Parent is a child of another Object.

How would i do that?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you just filter where `parentId` is not null?

Comment: Sorry my bad!  I Updated the Question